# OracleDriver ClassNotFound

Tags: java, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

I am a new user of IntelliJ, i am trying to connect my app to my database and i am getting the following.
I've tried to add the ojdbc6 jar into my project anywhere (/lib, Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies, Project Structure -> Modules -> Libraries, src/lib)
and i can't connect to my database using the following:

```
Sql.newInstance(URL,USER,PASSWORD,"oracle.jdbc.OracleDataSource")
```

Logs:

```
Class
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Message
null
Caused by
oracle.jdbc.OracleDataSource
```

Comment: Is your projecf a Maven project?

Comment: yes i am using Maven when i am keeping ojdbc6 jar in pom.xml then it is working.

Comment: Go through : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project